# Inserting #' to a configuration file using sed

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I'm trying to use sed to insert a `#` to a configuration file. I've tried:

```
sed 's/33/#' /path/to/file
```

But get the output

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated `s' command
```

I've also tried

```
sed -i '33i#' /path/to/file
```

Which adds the `#` into line 33, but moves the text I want to comment down one line.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you added the trailing slash to `'s/33/#/'`, it would replace occurrences of `33` with `#`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution you're after is:

```
sed -i '33s/^/#/' /path/to/file
```